# How to get all databases on LocalDb installed by different users?

Tags: sql-server, database, windows-services, localdb, sql-server-2012-localdb

When I run our service stand alone or when I run the same service as windows service logged on as the current Windows user then I cannot see the databases on LocalDb installed by the same Windows service when it was launched logged on as LocalSystem.
And the other way around, the same code that is supposed to get the list of installed on LocalDb server databases, doesn't return those installed databases, if the latter were installed on the LocalDb server by an application started as current Windows user and if the current service is running logged on as LocalSystem and we try to get the databases on the server.

I tried getting the databases on the LocalDb server two different ways and the list is the same for both ways.

```
// First way executing the following sql query from my C# code:
string query = $"SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4";

// Second way using the Server class as below (which probably under the hood does the same as the first way):
new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(localdb)\\v11.0").Databases
```

I know there are permission and authentication differences whether we connect to LocalDb server from the code that runs in the Windows Service and the latter is logged on as current user or LocalSystem, that's why the databases on the server might not be visible from one case to another.

My question is how can I get the complete list of databases installed by any users any time?

Comment: LocalDB is *designed* to be local to the user; if you have multiple users with LocalDB on the same host then each user will have their own databases. If you want a shared instance, LocalDB is the **wrong** choice. You need to install some kind of SQL Server as a *service*, most likely SQL Server Express, and you probably want it hosted on  a *dedicated* host.

Comment: Use SQL Server Express instead

Comment: @ThomA LocalDB does support shared instances but needs configuring https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16#shared-instances-of-localdb

Comment: True, though I wouldn't ever really use it in that scenario, @Charlieface .

Comment: I agree, one user shouldn't see DBs installed on the server by another user, but I was hoping that DBs installed by the LocalSystem would be visible to all other users if somehow permissions are granted.

Comment: No, you can't have a half and half scenario, @TigerGalo . Though if you had a full instance, access to databases, and data, could easily be handled with permissions.

Comment: If anything the opposite: stuff that SYSTEM has access to should not be touched by anyone else. Setup a shared instance if you have to, otherwise just use SQL Server Express.